# Historic and future (next) round of machine readable dividend info

Tags: data, programming, historical-data

Is there a source of historic dividend dates, ex-dividend dates and dividend values? Also, the next dividend date / ex-dividend date.

Ideally in a machine readable form? The publically available APIs don't seem to have the above info as an optional form of info.

[UpcomingDividends](http://www.upcomingdividends.co.uk/) seems to have some of the future data and [Google Finance](http://www.google.co.uk/finance?q=LON%3ABA&ei=Zm-KV7rmOdbEsAHj3JrgBQ) seems to have the last dividend info (although no date).

Comment: I'd be very surprised if you found decent quality dividend data.

Comment: @George_Edwards take a look and see if that did the trick.

Comment: @George_Edwards ?

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

> **Zacks Splits, Dividends and Corporate Actions Data**

[image: Image of Zacks Splits, Dividends and Corporate Actions Data]

Source: [Zacks Splits, Dividends and Corporate Actions Data](http://www.zacksdata.com/data/splits-dividends-corp-actions/)

Data on Quandl API: [Quandl Zacks Dividends Announcement and History](https://www.quandl.com/data/ZDIV)