# Free dividend data API for non-US stocks

Tags: equities, programming, dividends

Is there are any free API for dividend data that does also include non-US stocks?

I know of [this question from three years ago](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/28114/historic-and-future-next-round-of-machine-readable-dividend-info). However, the situation has changed since then apparently, as there are now at least options for US stocks.

Both https://iexcloud.io/ and https://www.alphavantage.co have free options for US stocks dividends data, but no global offering.

I would like to build a free and open source web-based tool that works with this data.

Comment: I know of a site that has US and Chinese dividend data as well as data on a bunch of ADRs but not a 'global offering' beyond that.  Would that be helpful?

Answer (score 3):

Yahoo Finance

For example

- BASF (listed in Germany): https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BAS.DE/history?period1=796867200&period2=1589932800&interval=div%7Csplit&filter=div&frequency=1d
- Roche (listed in Switzerland):  https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ROG.SW/history?period1=796867200&period2=1589932800&interval=div%7Csplit&filter=div&frequency=1d
- Airbus (listed in France): https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AIR.PA/history?period1=999475200&period2=1589932800&interval=div%7Csplit&filter=div&frequency=1d
- Santander (Spain): https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SAN.MC/history?period1=946857600&period2=1589932800&interval=div%7Csplit&filter=div&frequency=1d

etc.

The data is available as CSV, the URL GET arguments are self-explanatory. There's also libraries in R (quantmod), Python and others with ready functions to pull the data.

Answer (score -1):

finki.io does a great dividend API